# Возможно ли экспортировать данные из БД в Excel?

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

Возможно ли экспортировать данные из БД в Excel?

Comment: экспортируйте в `csv` а его откроете в Excel.

Comment: а через скрипт возможно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356578/how-to-output-mysql-query-results-in-csv-format

ну на ответ не сильно тянет, потому как ответ на такой поставлный вопрос будь на подобие "да можно", но приведу сдесь:

```
SELECT order_id,product_name,qty
FROM orders
WHERE foo = 'bar'
INTO OUTFILE '/var/lib/mysql-files/orders.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Answer (score 0):

С помощью php
 [Библиотека PHPexcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/136593)

Comment: @VAndrJ, название библиотеки не может стать недействительным. http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1639/178988

Comment: Мммм... воообще, такие тексты обычно комментариями принято оставлять, если неохота их расписывать подробнее. http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/4578/